# Webpack 3 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined'

Tags: jquery, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-3

I'm trying to add jQuery in the bundle, so far webpack 3 is not making it easy, i've seen the question asked several times, and none of the answers worked.

I added all the parts that are supposed to make this work

In webpack.config.js

```
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

In entry file: app.jsx

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

Webpack compiles, but in the browser I get the same error
[image]

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/Macromeda/Boilerplate), incase anyone wanna take a look at the files

Thanks alot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), not DefinePlugin. And also remove "externals" section.

Comment: By the way, you don't need this `window.$ = window.jQuery = ` statement when you using ProvidePlugin.